# What is the interpretation of $\pi(x) |0\rangle $?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators

In the second chapter of Peskin and Schroeder *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* after second quantization of the Klein-Gordon field we arrive at $$|p\rangle =\sqrt{2 E_p} a^{\dagger}_{p}\ |0\rangle$$ being interpreted as a single particle eigenstate with momentum $p.$

We also derive
$$\phi(x)\ |0\rangle =\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_p} e^{-i p \cdot x} |p\rangle .$$
Except for the factor of $1/2E_p$, this is the same as the non relativistic expression for the eigenstate of position $|x \rangle.$ We therefore put forward the interpretation that the operator $\phi(x),$ acting on the vacuum, creates a particle at position $x.$ Furthermore,
$$\langle 0 |\phi(x) | p\rangle = e^{i p \cdot x},$$
which lends more credence to the observation. This is all well and good. My question is, what is the interpretation of $\pi(x)\ |0\rangle$, where $\pi(x)$ is the conjugate momentum? Modulo a phase, it seems to give the *nonrelativistic* expression of an eigenstate of position $|x \rangle,$ although I am not quite sure if that is meaningful in this context.

Comment: Could [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155826/field-operators-in-klein-gordon-field-creation-of-a-particle-at-position-x) answer your question?

Comment: @SuperCiocia Yes, I like your answer! It would still be interesting to see if there *could* be an interpretation, but maybe there isn't really

Comment: Are you asking if $\pi(x)|0\rangle$ is a single-particle state? Or are you asking more specifically whether that particle is concentrated near $x$? Or are you asking even more specifically whether it's *perfectly* localized at the single point $x$, in the same way that a particle can be (arbitrarily close to) perfectly localized at a point in a nonrelativistic model?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly None of the above, I am asking if there is *any* physically meaningful (and intuitive) interpretation to give to it. $\phi(x) | 0 \rangle$ has the physically intuitive interpretation as "a particle at position $x.$ What can we say about $\pi(x) | 0 \rangle,$ if anything?